# Best way to make a vertical table

Tags: html, html-table

Is there an easier way to write this table with info flowing vertically instead of horizontally?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr><th>letters</th</tr>
        <tr><td>a</td></tr>
        <tr><td>b</td></tr>
        <tr><td>c</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Numbers</th</tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How should your table look like? And what do you mean by "flowing vertically"? Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you want to do.

Comment: Ccsyphus solves issue. I added inline styling to it and vwoalla it works great. Thank you.

Comment: Done. I checked an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, one would create two tables:

```html
<table>
    <tr><th>letters</th></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>b</td></tr>
    <tr><td>c</td></tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr><th>Numbers</th></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Would one need to use css to put two lists next to each other?